# How to fix Java 11 Generics type safety warning

Tags: java, generics, java-11, type-erasure

I have some requirements for the heterogeneous generic implementation for different types of Java objects. I can see warnings related to unchecked conversion. Any thought on the below implementation to avoid any runtime exception. Please find the below sample code.

```
class GenericData<T> {
  
  private final Class<T> type;
  private final static Map<Class<?>, GenericData> map = new HashMap<>(); //Warning :: GenericData is a raw type. References to generic type GenericData<T> should be parameterized

  public final static <T> GenericData<T> of(Class<T> type) {
    return map.putIfAbsent(type, new GenericData<T>(type)); // Warning :: Type safety: The expression of type GenericData needs unchecked conversion to conform to GenericData<T>
  }
  
  private GenericData(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  
  public final T getDataAfterDefaultValueApplied(T Data, T Body) {
    Map<String, Object> defaultMap = getDataMap(Data);
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = getDataMap(Body);
    defaultMap.putAll(dataMap);
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(defaultMap, type);
  }

  private Map<String, Object> getDataMap(T data) {
    // Demo implementation, ignore this one
    return (Map<String, Object>) data;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `GenericData` alone (without a `<...>`) if you want to avoid warnings and have this type-checked. That's a raw type and [using raw types is a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Guessing at the goal of this class, I'd guess that you'll need *some* unchecked cast at some point, because you want to put objects of different types in a single map and extract them in a type-safe way. That's not really possible if the only difference between the types is a type-parameter (i.e. `GenericData<X>` vs `GenericData<Y>`).

Comment: I can understand the GenericData must be used with <> and yes you are right with the example (i.e. GenericData<X> vs GenericData<Y>).

And I did a small modification that rather than storing raw type GenericData, any thought on this modification :


private final static Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();


public final static <T> GenericData<T> of(final Class<T> type) {

    return (GenericData<T>) map.putIfAbsent(type, new GenericData<T>(type)); 

 }

Comment: This avoids the raw type, but still has an unchecked cast (since you're casting to `GenericData<T>`. The runtime can only check if the object is any `GenericData<?>`, but it can't check if it's specifically a `GenericData<T>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For containers of this kind, an unchecked operation is unavoidable. But you should try to minimize it and further, add a runtime check to ensure type safety:

```java
class GenericData<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final static Map<Class<?>, GenericData<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public final static <T> GenericData<T> of(Class<T> type) {
        return map.putIfAbsent(type, new GenericData<>(type)).checkedCast(type);
    }

    private GenericData(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <U> GenericData<U> checkedCast(Class<U> clazz) {
        if(clazz != this.type) throw new ClassCastException(clazz + " != " + this.type);
        return (GenericData<U>)this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here, the unchecked operations are limited to the `checkedCast` method and it’s immediately recognizable to the reader that it has been made safe by an explicit check operation and only the compiler can’t recognize it.